# I want to show time interval of 30 minutes/

Tags: php

I am working on doctor appointment system ,In which doctor will first enter its start time and close time like 10:00 am to 6:00 pm.If user wants the doctor appointment it will book according.I want to show timing by the interval of 30 minutes.like 10:00 - 10:30 , 10:30-11:00.upto end time.It will select start time and end time from the database. How can i do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share please your code. Which database are you using?

Comment: So whats the problem? Just create simple html select with data you need.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please do not ask us to write your code for you.

Comment: I want to show timing by the interval of 30 minutes gap.I have only start time and end time in the database.

Comment: @RahulPamnani. I have found out a solution. You will crack on using my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
do connection to database
get result from database with start and endtime

new array

while startTime is not equal to endTime
    startTime + 30 minutes

    insert into array startTime 
while end

generate selectbox with array values

show selectbox
```

This is how you could do it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `strtotime` in order to achieve what you want.

```
$starttime = '9:00';  // your start time
$endtime = '21:00';  // End time
$duration = '30';  // split by 30 mins

$array_of_time = array ();
$start_time    = strtotime ($starttime); //change to strtotime
$end_time      = strtotime ($endtime); //change to strtotime

$add_mins  = $duration * 60;

while ($start_time <= $end_time) // loop between time
{
   $array_of_time[] = date ("h:i", $start_time);
   $start_time += $add_mins; // to check endtie=me
}
```

Output can be obtained using the belo code.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array_of_time);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output for the above code will be like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 09:00
    [1] => 09:30
    [2] => 10:00
    [3] => 10:30
    [4] => 11:00
    [5] => 11:30
    [6] => 12:00
    [7] => 12:30
    [8] => 01:00
    [9] => 01:30
    [10] => 02:00
    [11] => 02:30
    [12] => 03:00
    [13] => 03:30
    [14] => 04:00
    [15] => 04:30
    [16] => 05:00
    [17] => 05:30
    [18] => 06:00
    [19] => 06:30
    [20] => 07:00
    [21] => 07:30
    [22] => 08:00
    [23] => 08:30
    [24] => 09:00
)
```

Comment: @Rahul Pamnani. Let me know if you face any hindrance in development while using my code.

Comment: Thank you very much.But the problem is i want to show this timing in table.like 9:00 - 9:30. next row 9:30 to 10:00.Please help.@Naresh Kumar.P

Comment: @RahulPamnani. I have answered your question right first. Now this is your extra question that you are asing after you have got the output. You shall credit for this answer and we shall discuss that once you have credited. Since all are wanting to share knowledge based on credits in SO.

Comment: And i am sure i am here to help you in this regards. You share me how you want the table to display so that i shall code and let you know on that..

Comment: Ya sure we shall proceed from here on

Comment: It is showing me output like Array
(
    [0] => 09:00
). In the table i have loop condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123508/discussion-between-rahul-pamnani-and-naresh-kumar-p).

Comment: Thank you very much.@Naresh Kumar.

Comment: @RahulPamnani. Glad helping you bro. Happy coding